# .resx files in Visual Studio, Intellisense not updating?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Using *Visual Studio 2013*.

I have added a new resource file in my project and the resource file is called *Messages.resx*.  If I have a string in there with `MessageA` as the key, I can type `Messages.` and Intellisense will offer `MessageA` as a valid property.

[image: Example of a simple resource file]

[image: Intellisense working correctly]

Now if I rename `MessageA` to `MessageB`, Intellisense doesn't appear to update:

[image: MessageA has been renamed to MessageB]
[image: Intellisense has not updated]

It gets stranger - if I then add a new item to the file, we're back in business:

[image: New item 'MessageC' added]
[image: Intellisense gets updated]

But as soon as I rename one, Intellisense seems to revert to the original 'state':

[image: MessageC renamed to MessageD]
[image: Intellisense reverts to the original state]

**In short** it seems as though Intellisense is only updating when I add or remove an item to a resource file.  If I rename a key, it reverts back to some previous state.  Is this a problem within my project, perhaps an incorrect setting somewhere? Or could it be a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Two things I've noticed, 1. intellisense doesn't update in real time, and 2. CTRL-ALT-B to rebuild usually forces the issue

Comment: It should rename as soon as you switch to a different row on the resource editor. In other words, the pen icon should go away. Adding another property just does that (i.e switch to another row).

Comment: @Steve yeah, I noticed that rebuilding works, but for example in Visual Studio 2010 that wasn't required, it would automatically update all references if you renamed a key.

Comment: @Mrchief Yep, it should, but it's not, sadly.

Comment: I'm using Update 3, maybe that's a factor? If not, are there any file lock related issues (placed by either SCM provider or anitvirus) or similar?

Comment: @Mrchief "Update 3" you could be right, I'll try updating. (Currently using Update 2).

Comment: I'm using update 3 also...I am impatient, so I just hit a build, for me, its usually fast. I wonder if I waited long enough till the parser catches up if it will eventually work likes its supposed to, but again, i'm impatient.